# Finding all detailDislosureButtons on a view

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I'm attempting to find all buttons of a particular type (`detailDisclosure`) on a `UIViewController`. To find all `UIButtons` on a view, I'd use the following:

```
let buttons = view.subviews.filter{$0 is UIButton}
```

How would I filter by the button type, in this case a [`detailDisclosure`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibuttontype)?

I've tried using UIButtonType w/ raw value of 2 and with `UIButtonType.detailDisclosure`, but I get a compiler error.

```
    let buttons = view.subviews.filter{$0 is UIButtonType.detailDisclosure}
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your filter closure you first need to check if each view is a `UIButton` using the conditional type cast operator (`as?`). If it is a button, you can then check if the `buttonType` property is `.detailDisclosure`.

```
let buttons = view.subviews.filter {
    guard let button = $0 as? UIButton else {
        return false
    }
    return button.buttonType == .detailDisclosure
}
```

---

For an equivalent single-line solution, you can use optional chaining with the `buttonType` property, but note that you have to prepend the type onto `.detailDisclosure` (`UIButtonType`) because it can no longer be inferred.

```
buttons = view.subviews.filter { ($0 as? UIButton)?.buttonType == UIButtonType.detailDisclosure }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ....

```
let buttons = view.subviews.filter { (v) -> Bool in
    if let btn = v as? UIButton {
        if btn.buttonType == .detailDisclosure {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is swift 2.3 but you can do something like this in your filter method

```
if buton.buttonType == UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure {

}
```

Comment: ButtonType is a readonly property, so its probably working... are you changing the code i pasted to match yours?

Answer (score 0):

This one is working for me perfectly: (Swift 3)

```
let buttons = view.subviews.filter{$0 is UIButton}

for btn in buttons as! [UIButton] {
    if btn.buttonType == .detailDisclosure {
        print(bin)
    }
}
```